# Hyperledger Fabric: CreateChannel Issue version-2

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode, golang-migrate, hyperledger-fabric-orderer

fabric fabric-samples/test-network createChannel failed
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJLk3.png

Answer (score 0):

At the point of failure, it can't connect to 7050, which is the port for the orderer node. If you do a `docker ps` it should at least tell you if that peer is currently running and that it really is available on that port. Are the YAML files exactly as you found them or did you make any amendments? Configuration is sometimes the biggest culprit if you are not careful about managing the changes.